# Make a \hole larger?

Tags: xy-pic

In order to make the arrow go behind 'B' I use \hole.

```
\xymatrix{ A \ar[ddrr]|\hole \\ & B \\ & & C }
```

But what if I have something big instead of 'B', such as

```
\xymatrix{ A \ar[ddrr]|\hole \\ & \text{\Huge{B}}_\text{\Huge{B}} \\ & & C }
```

Then the hole is too small. How do I make a large hole?

Answer (score 2):

Use your big object as the label for the arrow inside `|{...}` so it will be over the arrow line.

```
\[
\xymatrix@C=2cm{%            %% @C= just to space the columns
 A \ar[dr] | {\text{\Huge{B}}_\text{\Huge{B}}} & \\  %% |{} is the trick
 & C 
}
\]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix@C=2cm{ A \ar[dr]|{\text{\Huge{B}}_\text{\Huge{B}}} & \\  & C } \]
\end{document}
```